# Why did Megyn specifically mention that nobody from the weather department wants Lily’s job?

Tags: plot-explanation, bombshell

In a scene from Bombshell (2019), with a list in her hand, Fox anchor Megyn walks into a room with a feeling
of achievement on her face, puts on her heels, and meets Doug, Lily, and Julia:

> Megyn: I've got names. Women rumored to have stories about Roger.
>
> Julia: From who?
>
> Megyn: Janice.
>
> Lily: Weather Janice?
>
> Megyn: Everybody confides in her. **Nobody from Weather wants your job**.

Megyn takes up a task on her own to find out the names of those who
suffered from Roger Ailes. So, acknowledging the fact that nobody from
the weather department wants Lily’s job sounds out of context.

Why did Megyn specifically mention that nobody from the weather department wants Lily’s job?

Comment: (Weather) Janice will talk to (News) Lily because they're not competing for each other's jobs. Their career trajectories are different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "your" here doesn't mean Lily; it's the [Generic You](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_you), as found in phrases such as "Brushing your teeth is healthy" or "You have to be careful with your money".

Megyn is saying: Janice has names *because* everybody from News confides in her *because* she is a 'safe' confidant. And she is a safe confidant for someone who works in News *because* she doesn't want *the confider's* job.